# Jump is glitching but get no errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I coded this script for a basic (FPS) player controller, but when jumping it doesn't work. It works but it's very glitchy. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    public int Speed;
    public float SprintMultipliyer = 2f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float JumpHeight;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;

    private float a = 1f;
    private float SprintSpeed = 1;
    private float HorizontalInput;
    private float ForwardInput;

    bool IsonGround;

    Vector3 velocity;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        IsonGround = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        //this checks if the player is on the ground and his vertical [y] is less then 0 (which is good for a one height and not good for multiple different heights)
        if (IsonGround)
        {
            velocity.y = -3f;
        }
        //this if statement ischecking if the player presses [spacebar] and if he is on the ground
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsonGround)
        {
            //the math for a jump is: the square root of the height you want to jump times [*] -2 * gravity or in the program: Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Sprint") && IsonGround)
        {
            SprintSpeed = a * SprintMultipliyer;
        }
        else
        {
            SprintSpeed = 1;
        }
        

        //Input.GetAxis("[name of the axis]") is used to set the variables to 1 when the player presses [A/D] or [W/S]
        HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        ForwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //this works by = transform is multiplied with HorizontalInput [A/D] and then multipliyng transform.forward with ForwardInput [W/S]
        Vector3 move = transform.right * HorizontalInput + transform.forward * ForwardInput;

        //controller is a public CharacterControler that is called [controller]
        //.Move is a function similar to transform.Translate
        //move is a Vector3 that is used for left/right and forward/backward input
        controller.Move(move * Speed * SprintSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I tried changing the gravity, jump height and ground distance but still doesn't work correctly. The ground distance object is also on the ground and and the ground is on the ground layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I putted the groundCheck object on the ground layer and set the ground distance on 0.1 and works fine with no glitches